# ID's being stripped out of editor for Admin user in Multi-Site

Tags: multisite, admin, tags, editor, html-editor

I have a Multi-Site install running on the current version of WordPress (3.3.1). The problem I'm having is the ID's are being stripped out of my tags in the editor. When I am logged in as a "Super Admin", the ID's **are NOT** stripped out. When I am logged in as an "Admin", the ID's **are** stripped out.

Here is an example of the valid HTML being used:

```
<ul class="tabs-content">
    <li id="tab1-tab" class="active">Tab 1 content</li>
    <li id="tab2-tab">Tab 2 content</li>
    <li id="tab3-tab">Tab 3 content</li>
</ul>
```

After updating the post as an admin, here is the result, every time:

```
<ul class="tabs-content">
    <li class="active">Tab 1 content</li>
    <li>Tab 2 content</li>
    <li>Tab 3 content</li>
</ul>
```

This issue can be reproduced by setting up a WordPress multisite install. Create an Super Admin (setup on install) and a new user with Admin privileges. Try adding the HTML in the first code example with the ID's in it. The Super Admin account will not strip the ID's, the Admin account will.

Anyone know of a fix, plugin, or reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just run into this today.  It's almost like Multisite doesn't respect the `unfiltered_html` capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this has something to with the way a Multi-site intall handles unfiltered_html capabilities between Super Admins and Admins. The problem was resolved using the [Unfiltered MU plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unfiltered-mu/), however, beaware of the warning stated on the plugin page.